# How to use device name in ble scan filter in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've burned a few hours on this one and can't seem to get past this. I've seen in an old stack overflow post (about 5 yrs ago) that ble scan filtering on a device name was broken in Android, so you had to do it manually on each of the returned scan results. I'm hoping that it's fixed by now and I'm just making a newbie error that someone can easily spot.

I'm using Kotlin to perform a ble scan. **My code works fine when the filter is null**, but I have been unable to get it to work using a device name (advertised device name) as a filter. **The code below with a filter compiles, but crashes on my Nexus 7 tablet (Android 6.0.1) when I start the ble scan** (I've included only what I hope is relevant for clarity).

I'm using the following code (all in MainActivity.kt) to create the filter for a device named **"RCTL003"**:

```
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter as LeScanFilter
// After the class declaration for MainActivity
// Here's the scanner.
private val bleScanner by lazy {
    bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner
}
// Here's the device name "RCTL003"
private val filter = LeScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName("RCTL003").build()
private lateinit var devfilters: MutableList<LeScanFilter>
...
// I init devfilters just before I start the scan in my startBleScan function
devfilters.add(filter)
bleScanner.startScan(devfilters, scanSettings, scanCallback)
```

The bleScanner.startScan takes a mutable list of type ScanFilter:

```
startScan((Mutable)List<ScanFilter!>!, ScanSettings!, ScanCallback!) defined in android.bluetooth.le
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Jim

Comment: I'll suggest try [this](https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleBluetoothTerminal) its best example for Android BLE

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've looked through the code at the link, but didn't see anything related to scan filtering. It may be that scan filtering on a device name is still broken so I'll have to manually filter with code : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing how devFilters is defined scan filter by device name does work!

devFilters above should be defined as:

```
private devfilters: MutableList<LeScanFilter> = ArrayList()
```

I'm using a minSdk of 23.